# Не правильно открывается SQLite БД в PyCharm

Tags: sqlite, pycharm

Искользую pyCharm
Суть такая, раньше при таком коде:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('name.db')
cursor_obj = con.cursor()
cursor_obj.execute('create table if not exists birthday('
                   'id_accaunt integer PRIMARY KEY, '
                   'name_user text, '
                   'date date)')
con.close()
```

Создавался файл 'name.db' иконка у него была базы данных[image: введите сюда описание изображения] и при открытии делался коннект с ним и можно было посмотреть что в нем есть(таблицы, колонки).

Теперь создается файл 'name.db'на иконке написано sql[image: введите сюда описание изображения] и открывается как простой файл без ничего[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал: удалять и создавать по новой, менять в настройках диалект(вероятно что-то там не то сделал)

И такая проблема только в одном проекте, в других все нормально. Как в этом вернуть исходное состояние открытия DB

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать DB Browser (SQLite) вместо Database пайчармовской. Сбоев таких не наблюдал на ней. Тогда как пайчармовская Database вероятно нужна для чего-то более серьезного чем sqlite3.
*Диалект кстати под sqlite3 всегда какой-то не такой, неподбираемый.

Comment: А вопрос этот лучше вовсе задать в разделе тех. поддержки Pycharm-a

Answer (score 1):

Это не ошибка и не проблемма, так БД шифруеться и через текствовый редактор БД не открыть и будут проблеммы с кодировкой, используйте программы для открытия с убодным просмотром БД, такие как:

- https://inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer/
- https://sqlitebrowser.org/

Есть вариан и через Пайчарм:

View -> Tool Windows -> Database

(У вас файл открыт в режиме редактора текста)

> P.S. В PyCharm Community Edition этой фичи нет.

Answer (score -1):

Следующий скриншот по решению проблемы.
Это работает если у Вас Professional Pycharm.
После это нужно будет открыть файл в DB (database) и скорее всего таблиц там не будет, нужно будет в терминале сделать миграцию при помощи команды python manage.py migrate.
[image: Продолжение]

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).